# Unicorn Procfile and development databases (Ruby on Rails 4, PostgreSQL, Heroku, Resque)

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn, resque, procfile

I am developing a **RoR4 app** using a **Postgre** database that does some background database processing with <kbd>[resque](https://github.com/resque/resque/tree/1-x-stable)</kbd> and is hosted on **Heroku**. My question regards running locally for development.

It is my understanding (in this particular project) that when I start the web server using `rails server`, it connects to a development database, and when I start it using `foreman start` (with an appropriate Procfile), it connects to some other local database.

My problem is that my **Resque** jobs look for ActiveRecords in the development database, forcing me to use `rails server`. However, I need to access some environment variables, stored in a `.env` file, and it is my understanding that only `foreman` is able to read these environment variables.

How do I approach a workaround for this problem?

More specifically, how can I get my **Resque** jobs to look for ActiveRecords in the same database that `foreman start` uses? Or, how do I have `foreman start` use the the development database?

My guess for the latter would be edit the Procfile, but I haven't had luck finding a simple solution.

Procfile.dev:

`web: bundle exec unicorn -c ./config/unicorn.rb -E $RAILS_DEV`

NOTE: $RAILS_DEV=development

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem is. It turns out that my `.env` file had an explicit URL to connect to my Heroku database. Once I removed that line, `foreman start` connected to my development database.